Similarity measure between copulas
I have five 1,000,000$\times$30 matrices labeled as $M_1, M_2, M_3, M_4, M_5$. Each column in these matrices consists of random uniforms $\in[0, 1]$. The five $30\times 30$ covariance matrices are almost identical.
I need to determine which matrix among $\{M_2, M_3, M_4, M_5\}$ is most "similar" to $M_1$, i.e., which one in $\{M_2, M_3, M_4, M_5\}$ is most likely a sample from the same copula as $M_1$.
For convenience, we can even assume every column in every matrix contains integers $\in[1, 1000000]$.
So, what is an efficient similarity measure of two dependency structures (copulas)? Here I want to rule out any approach related to covariance matrices, because they are almost identical.
I am aware of the Earth Mover's Distance (EMD), which can be a general recipe for measuring distance between two multivariate distributions. But since we are only interested in copulas and EMD is computationally expensive, are there any short cuts?
Naively, I can think of many heuristics. For example, I could
(i) order $M_1$ and $M_2$ by their 1st columns,
(ii) compute the sum of squared differences between the matrices element-wisely,
(iii) repeat (i) and (ii) for every column,
(iv) add all the sums of squared differences.
The final sum would be the distance between the two copulas.
Alternatively, I can compute the eigen vectors of $M_1$ and $M_2$, ordered by their respective eigen values, and then compute the weighted (by squared eigen values) sum of squared Euclidean distance between the eigen vectors.
Can anyone offer some practical insights on this?
